# Maintaining Oracle DB SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: 2011-sp1, database, oracle

We are planning to run DB maintenance scripts on our Oracle Database.

From documentation I came to know that we need to run the following scripts.

```
AnalyzeStats.sql
ShowTableStats.sql
ShowColumnStats.sql
ShowIndexStats.sql
RebuildIndexes.sql
PrepareAnalyzeStatsEx.sql
AnalyzeStatsEx.sql
```

Do we need to follow any sequence?

Is it enough if we run these scripts as username mentioned below in image or as DBA?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't that same documentation explain what these scripts do? (It does, AFAIK)

Only `AnalyzeStats.sql` and `RebuildIndexes.sql` are intended for regular maintenance; the other scripts are analytical -- to get insight in the state of the DB and whether maintenance is needed.